# Validate potential new rows to add to DataGridView from a .BIN file

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview, .net-3.5

### Ignore/skip the first constant record which contains info like store id, location and date opened... Read the rest (info like purchase id, item name, date purchased)...

I am creating an application that decodes .bin files and displays info into a DataGridView table. When a row is selected more info is displayed into additional fields. However, unwanted data is always added in the first row of each file and sometimes the last row. I want to validate this and display only if validation's pass. My code simply adds what it sees after some conversion. When a user selects a file to import, the method Info_to_Table is called.

```
byte[] rec_arr = new byte[32767];
private void Info_to_Table()
{
    rec_arr = File.ReadAllBytes(import.FileName);
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(import.FileName);
    long length = fi.Length;
    long count = 0;

    using (FileStream Fs = new FileStream(import.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (BinaryReader Br = new BinaryReader(Fs))
    {
        // Read other info here

        while ((length = Br.Read(rec_arr, (int)0, 1024)) > 0) *
        {
            // Read other info here
            Dgv.Rows.Add(DecodeLong(rec_arr, 4), count++, DecodeDateTime(rec_arr, 28));
        }

        Br.Close();
        Fs.Close();
    }
}
```

When a record (row) is selected:

```
private void Dgv_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    To_Fields();
}
```

Each time a record is selected:

```
private void To_Fields()
{           
    rec_arr = File.ReadAllBytes(import.FileName);
    FileInfo file_info_bin = new FileInfo(import.FileName);
    long length_bin = file_info_bin.Length;
    int rec_num_to_read = Dgv.CurrentRow.Index;

    using (FileStream FS = new FileStream(import.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (BinaryReader BR = new BinaryReader(FS))
    {
        do
        {
            FS.Seek(rec_num_to_read * 1024, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            // Read other info here!
            Status(rec_arr);

            foreach (var rec in rec_arr)
            {
                rec_num_to_read++;
            }
        }
        while ((length_bin = BR.Read(rec_arr, 0, 1024)) > 0);

        BR.Close();
        FS.Close();
    }
}
```

Is there a way of validating the file information before it populates the table? Ignoring any isn't correct? It's the entire row that is wrong if the first column's number is larger than 22500.

### What it does now, this is **wrong**:

[image]

### What I would like it to do, this is **correct**:

[image]

Each record in the file is 1024 characters long. I thought the solution would be in the line with * as here I am reading bytes from the stream with index as the starting point in the array. *byte[], index, count*.

Generally, the files look like this and all have the same structure: (large file with 682 records)

[image]

Comment: Did you try to debug and see why and where the unwanted data comes from? When you run your code on the same file, the results are different?

Comment: Can you post your full code where Dgv populated?

Comment: We don't know enough about your data to help with your validation.  The two suspect rows also have dates from the 1990's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide any description of the data you're dealing with, it's hard to come up with anything better than this:

```
while ((length = Br.Read(rec_arr, (int)0, 1024)) > 0) *
{
    // Read other info here
    var foo = DecodeLong(rec_arr, 4);

    if (foo != 825045041)
        Dgv.Rows.Add(foo, count++, DecodeDateTime(rec_arr, 28));
}
```

And in the `To_Fields` method you can just skip one record:

```
int rec_num_to_read = Dgv.CurrentRow.Index + 1;
```

---

However, I tried to run your code with the data from the screenshot, and it didn't work. I skip 1024 bytes (the unwanted record) and what I get from the beginning of the next record doesn't seem to be valid either. The value is 542966816, and the date is just mess. I don't know the date format, but it's clear that there's something wrong.

I don't have enough reputation to post images, so here's a link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdIAa.gif

---

I'd like to add that several statements are useless.

You don't need to call `Close()`, that's what `using` is for. [Explanation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

```
Br.Close();
Fs.Close();
```

The other remarks are true, if there's no code you have omitted.

Reading is done in a loop, so `ReadAllBytes` is not needed.

```
rec_arr = File.ReadAllBytes(import.FileName);
```

`length` is not used either.

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(import.FileName);
long length = fi.Length;
```

---

And one more thing, `long` is 64 bit in C#. Use `int` which is 32 bit instead. So it's better to rename `DecodeLong` to `DecodeInt32`, because it's quite confusing really.

Comment: I tried your solution, although it correctly displayed the correct amount of records it still functions the same. When I select the first record being 1, it says the number is 825045041 in a field... Selecting record 2 says the number is 1 in a field. It's slightly hard to explain, but half way there. I have included a screenshot of the data in a .bin file I have been using, hope it helps.

Comment: What value and date should be in the second row?

Comment: I added the line to the To_Fields method, it's simple but genius! I don't know why I never thought of that, oh no! Thank you! :)

Comment: You're welcome! It's not general solution though. If there's an invalid record in the middle of the file, everything will go wrong.

Comment: Although it solved the first row issue, how about when the same value appears only sometimes in the last record? Basically, if the last 'foo' is equal to 825045041, then don't add the row. This doesn't happen all the time but does at times :/

Comment: If the last record value is 825045041, the row won't be added. But if there are invalid records in the middle of the file, rows will be skipped, the order will be mixed up and selected row index won't correspond to the record index inside the file. The hack allows to skip the first and any amount of records in the end safely but not in the middle.

Comment: The row **is** added though, only **sometimes** at the **end**, not at all in the middle. I'll look through my code again.

Comment: Can you post that .bin file somewhere?